# display the data in my li tag, I am getting the data in my console

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template, angular6

- I am trying to display the data in the browser
- when I hit the api call, I am getting the data in my console.
- but how to display the data in my li tag.
- providing my relevant code below and whole code in the gist

https://gist.github.com/niniyzni/2773b28246ae629dd83b8d6aa5e57185
https://gist.github.com/niniyzni/00ed267c0cd3b97e78fd90791e54ec51

```or-tag-here
myFunc() {
    console.log("function called");

    // this.navItems = this.http.get("../res/data.json");
    // console.log("this.navItems--->", this.navItems);

    this.http
      .get(
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/USA/all"
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log("data-------->", data);

        let result = data;
      });
  }


<div *ngFor="let r of result">
        <p>{{r.id}}</p>

    </div>

    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let r of result">
            <input type="text" name="food-name" [(ngModel)]="r.id">
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: At the moment, your `result` variable can only be accessed from within that `subscribe` function. Instead of `let result = data`, you should use `this.result = data`. As long as `result` is an array it should work

Comment: did my answer below solved your issue? Any feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change `let result = data;` to `this.result = data;`

```
myFunc() {
    console.log("function called");

    this.http
      .get(
        "..." // url
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log("data--->", data);
        this.result = data;
      });
  }
```

> let declares a block scope local variable to access to property of your class ues `this` so `this.result` how you can access to the `result` that you declared and used at the template with `ngFor`.

Answer (score 0):

result is declared and defined in `myFunc`. So can yo try setting a global variable instead

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "Angular Coding Exercise 6";

  constructor(private appService: AppService, private http: Http) {}

  navItems: any;
  result: any;
  myFunc() {
    console.log("function called");

    // this.navItems = this.http.get("../res/data.json");
    // console.log("this.navItems--->", this.navItems);

    this.http
      .get(
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/USA/all"
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log("data-------->", data);

        this.result = data;
      });
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it like this (using `async` pipe and mapping your result):

```
import { share, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

...

result$: Observable<Array<any>>;
...
myFunc() {
  console.log("function called");

  const url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/USA/all';
  this.result$ = this.http.get(url).pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log('CHECK IF RESPONSE IS SHARED')), 
    map(resp => resp.RestResponse.result), 
    share()
  );
}
```

your HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let r of result$ | async">
  <p>{{r.id}}</p>
</div>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let r of result$ | async">
    <input type="text" name="food-name" [(ngModel)]="r.id">
  </li>
</ul>
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5ffki?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

```
myFunc() {
    ------> result : any
    console.log("function called");
    this.http
      .get(
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/USA/all"
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log("data-------->", data);
        -----> this.result = data;
      });
  }
```